# Airflow Python yield statement

Tags: python, airflow

I know `yield` is used to define generators, replacing the return of a function to provide a result to its caller, but what do the following yield statements do? They don't look like generators, also yield are followed by return.

The code is from the file: `airflow/ti_deps/deps/task_concurrency_dep.py`

```py
class TaskConcurrencyDep(BaseTIDep):
    """
    This restricts the number of running task instances for a particular task.
    """
    NAME = "Task Concurrency"
    IGNOREABLE = True
    IS_TASK_DEP = True

    @provide_session
    def _get_dep_statuses(self, ti, session, dep_context):
        if ti.task.task_concurrency is None:
            yield self._passing_status(reason="Task concurrency is not set.")
            return

        if ti.get_num_running_task_instances(session) >= ti.task.task_concurrency:
            yield self._failing_status(reason="The max task concurrency "
                                              "has been reached.")
            return
        else:
            yield self._passing_status(reason="The max task concurrency "
                                              "has not been reached.")
            return
```

Comment: I think the return statements are dead code

Comment: The return is also used to raising StopIteration. so yield generates while return stops the code..